# Order of XML elements in ASMX web service response changes with the PC it is built on

Tags: .net, web-services, entity-framework-4, .net-4.0, asmx

In an ASMX web service, the method GetProductListModulesOnPage returns a list of ProductListModule objects. The ProductListModule class comes from 2 sources:

1. An Entity Framework 4 entity (generated using POCO template)
2. A partial class declaration that adds a single extra property as follows:

   `public partial class ProductListModule {
   public bool IsNotActivated { get; set; }
   }`

The problem is that the position of the IsNotActivated element in the web service response varies according to the machine the project is built on. On a colleague's PC, it appears at the very top, while on my PC, it appears at the very bottom, as here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetProductListModulesOnPageResponse xmlns="http://ecommerce.company.co.uk/">
      <GetProductListModulesOnPageResult>
        <ProductListModule>
          <ListPageTabID>364</ListPageTabID>
          <ListPageModuleID>872</ListPageModuleID>
          <ListPageCategoryID>107</ListPageCategoryID>
          <ProductCategory>
            <CategoryID>107</CategoryID>
            <CategoryName>Buff</CategoryName>
            <ParentCategoryID>343</ParentCategoryID>
            <Archived>false</Archived>
          </ProductCategory>
          <IsNotActivated>false</IsNotActivated>
        </ProductListModule>
      </GetProductListModulesOnPageResult>
      <Success>true</Success>
      <Message />
    </GetProductListModulesOnPageResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If the position changes (and the service reference is not refreshed), the web service client 
cannot interpret the response and an exception is thrown.

We can't see what is different between the machines doing the build (same VS version, same EF version), and we all work from the exact same source code.

We also tried controlling the serialisation order by adding the following attribute to the IsNotActivated property, but this had no effect.

`[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]`

PS - no points for suggesting converting to WCF !!

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.100).aspx, putting `[DataMember(Order = 1)]` on your partial class may actually move it to after the EF stuff.  Members with no `Order` appear first, in alphabetical order.